# Detecting Render Start on Webbrowser Control

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, mshtml, ihtmldocument2

Trying to figure out when the webbrowser control starts rendering (displays something) to the end user. Any idea on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the WebBrowser.[Navigated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.navigated.aspx) and Control.[Paint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint.aspx) events to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

1. IViewObject::SetAdvise on the browser control
2. IAdviseSink::OnViewChange
3. query the control  for IViewObject